# Frame size of Cannondale Synapse

Tags: road-bike, size, cannondale

I need to sell my husband's Cannondale Synapse. Can anyone tell me how I identify its frame size, please?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, there is a decal/sticker on the frame in the bottom bracket area  that will tell the size if it wasn't removed, typically in the range of 50 centimeters, or sizing like *XS-XL*. (Some brands also have it on the top tube or further up the seat tube, it depends).

[image]

Alternatively, you can go to a page featuring geometry data, look up the measurements for a bike and compare against the actual frame.

For example, here are the numbers for a 2022 Synapse: https://geometrygeeks.bike/bike/cannondale-synapse-2022/

You would need to know the approximate model year and model of the bike since there might be changes in geometry over the years.

[image]

I think, the safest measurement is the *top tube* or *seat tube*, these are often featured in small increments but it should usually get you to the correct ballpark of size if measured correctly.

Comment: The sticker on a cannondale is towards the top of the seat tube, above the 2nd bottle cage mount

Answer (score 3):

It should have a sticker on the frame, something like this:

[image]  This example is a 60 cm frame.